# How to create a folder structure in document folder through iTunes file sharing

Tags: iphone, ios5, file-sharing

I am developing application for ipad3 with file sharing through iTunes.Problem is that i can share only single file with my application.I want to add folders and sub folders to document folders.
How can i add folders to document folder through iTunes file sharing?

Answer (score 0):

You can create directories 
using `NSFileManager`

The method below will return the path to directory *userName* if it exists and create it if it doesn't.

```
+ (NSString *)getDocsDirectoryByUserName:(NSString *)userName 
{

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * documentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * userDir = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:userName];

NSError *error;
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:userDir 
                                         withIntermediateDirectories:YES 
                                                          attributes:nil error:&error];   

if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Error creating data path: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

return userDir;
}
```